# How to add dynamic alias to indexes in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, pipeline

I have a index template configured to apply on a index pattern `products_*`

How each document in `products` will have two fields

- `date`
- `country_code`

using the pipeline processor I wanted to create dynamic indexes like below

- `products_2021_12_24_us`
- `products_2021_12_25_us`
- `products_2021_12_24_uk`

now i want to add alias for the indexes in the following behavior

for a index `products_2021_12_24_us` the alias should be `products_us` and `products_2021_12_24`
so that we can search the `US` products under one name and also for one date products under one name.

What should i use here?
Should i create multiple templates or one template can handle it all?

Comment: The county part is easy to handle with two templates (the main one for all products and another one specific to each country code). However, for the date it is more complex, mainly because ingest processors can create indexes but cannot create aliases. The only way I can think of is to pre-create one template for each day, but it's not really elegant I think... In my opinion, searching by day is best achieved using a simple `range` query

Comment: The date partition is to have the ability to delete data that is gone above a certain limit. You can consider the date part to be of year-month wise. like 2021-08 as suffix. range query will still uses the full index and will be slower then picking a index with specific dates

Comment: is there no way to use the field value as alias suffix?

Comment: "range query will still uses the full index and will be slower then picking a index with specific dates" => that's not true if you make sure to index your data with [index time sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-index-sorting.html) (and that's how time series data should be indexed), i.e. only the relevant indexes will be searched

Comment: You can still have daily indexes (provided you don't create too many small indexes) to take care of your retention needs, but you certainly don't need daily aliases